# Any foreseeable issues with making 10000 different ActiveRecord SQLite DB connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I have a collection of ~10000 documents, each of which contain several SQLite DBs. (*)

I am thinking of automatically sub-classing the ActiveRecord models I am writing for the tables contained in these DBs based on the document identifier so I can call establish_connection on each class separately.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Document_xyz < Document
  establish_connection(.../xyz.sqlite)
end
```

Is this feasible, or should I try to merge all the databases together somehow (possibly by prefixing the ID on the table name, or as a column (?)) so I can just make a single connection?

* note: I cannot change this file setup since it is in use elsewhere, but I am making a web interface, so I am researching possibilities for handling such a large number if DBs.

Comment: Most OS have a limit on the number of open file handles that can be opened. Since sqlite is serverless, I guess the file handle limit will be counted against your program's file handle limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open as many database connections as you want per model. That said, exactly one connection per model would be way better and easier to code and use. But that many Connections will consume a huge amount of resources of your machine, so... iterate through all the different databases, grep their contents, and write it all to a single database file (don't forget to model a efficient relationship if possible).

After that, working with the database should be quite fast & easy.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially huge resources would be needed to do this.

You could write a rake task that will convert the databases into a json template then you can manipulate the data however you see fit without too much concern over server resources.

You really should request that json representations of the sqlite databases are supplied by the vendor.